# Pre-training for multi label classification

Tags: keras, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

I have to pre train a model for multi label classification. I'm pretraining with cifar10 dataset and I wonder if I have to use for the pre training
'categorical_crossentrpy' (softmax) or 'binary_crossentropy' (sigmoid), since in the first case I have a multi classification problem

Answer (score 1):

You should use `softmax` because it gives you the probabilities for every class, no matter how many of them are there. Sigmoid, as you have written is used with `binary_crossentropy` and is used in binary classification (hence binary in the name). I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know the difference, but in multilabel classification I have to use 'sigmoid' and 'binary_crossentropy'. So I wonder if also for the pre training in order to do transfer learning or fine tuning I have to use tha same functions

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. You say you have to use `sigmoid` and `binnary crossentropy` in multicalss classification and that is not possible. If you have more than 2 outputs of the model you have to use `softmax` with `categorical crossentropy`.  And to answer your question, if you want to do vanilla transfer learning (use the same exact model) then the answer is obvious because you use the same model. In case you want to use pretrained weights and initialize the different model's weights with it, I don't think you have to use the same activation function

Comment: But, softmax and sigmoid are normally used only on the output layer, so I don't know exactly what is the point of your question

Comment: Yes, they are only in the output. So, in your opinion I have to use 'categorical_crossentropy' and softmax for the pre training and then for the multi label classification 'binary_crossentropy' (sigmoid), since they are used only for the last layer, wich differs in the two cases. Am I right?

Comment: No. Whenever you have multilabel classification you have to use `softmax` with `categorical_crossentropy`. Both in pretraining and in reinforcement training. It's not dependable on your task, it's just the way it is. If you have anything multilabel you have to use `softmax` with `categorical_crossentropy` for classification.

Comment: Look here stackoverflow.com/questions/44164749/…. Despite usually softmax it's better that sigmoid, it can't be used for multi-label classification!

Comment: You don't understand the problem there. Look at the question. The person who asked the question has multiple correct answers, but in cifar you don't have that case. If you also have mutiple correct classes that can be found in one image, then you asked the question in the wrong way.

Comment: Indeed, if you deal with multi label classification means that every image has multi classes. As me he calls this problem multi label classification. It is my same problem! So my question was how pre train a model  in order to do multi label classification

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand that that was your problem. Then yes, use One-versus-rest approach. You can refer to the post you sent me. Do softmax for pretraining as in the cifar there is only one class correct and sigmoid in the transfer model